# Include precompiled zImage in yocto project

Tags: yocto, imx6

I have a custom board with imx6dl chip and peripherals. I have compiled u-boot, zImage and rootfs from examples provided by manufacturer. But when i try to build yocto from git repo with latests releases, it fails to run (some drivers not working, board is loading and display interface, but touchscreen is not working for ex.),
Is there any way to include precompiled binaries zImage, u-boot and device table to bitbake recipes? I'm very new to yocto project, and only need to get bootable image with working drivers and qt5.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a working boot chain (e.g. u-boot, kernel and device tree) that you have built out-of-yocto, then you might try building a rootfs only. This requires two main settings, to be made in your `local.conf` to get started. Please don't firget that this is just a starting point, and it is highly advised to get the kernel/bootloader build sorted out really soon.

`PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-dummy` to have no kernel being built, and something like `MACHINE="qemuarm"` to set up an armv7 build on poky later than version 3.0. The `core-image-minimal` target should at least be enough to drop you in a shell for starters, and then you can proceed from there.

Additionally, it might be qorth asking the board vendor or the yocto community (#yocto on the freenode server) if they know about a proper BSP layer. FSL things are quite nicely supported these days, and if your board is closely related to one of the well-known ones, you've got a high chance that [meta-freescale](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-freescale/) just does the trick nicely.

Addition:

@Martin pointed out the mention of Qemu is misleading. This is just the easiest way to make Yocto build a userland for the armv7-architecture which the imx6dl is based on. The resulting root filesystem should be sufficiently compatible to get started, before moving on to more tuned `MACHINE` configuration.